# RewriteRule without flag R

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Why this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([1-9]+)[^/]$ /$1/?utm_source=$2 [R,L]
```

work with R flag and without it doesn't work.
What's the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because without the `R` flag it's internal rewrite, it's not an actual redirect.

You can do some search on your own:

- Here's the wiki of [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)
- The [howto's htaccess official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)
- The [official mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

### Two hints to help you doing the job faster:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

https://regex101.com/ (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

You use this tool when you want to check the URL and see if they're valid or not.